# Let $(X_i)$ be i.i.d. exponential, is the set $\{X_1,X_2,\ldots\}$ almost surely dense in $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

To be clear, I'm asking if the range of the random sequence $(X_i)$ is dense in $(0,\infty)$ a.s.

I thinks the answer is yes, because for any $0<a<b<\infty$, we have

$$P(X_1 \notin (a,b), ..., X_n \notin (a,b)) = \alpha_{a,b}^n $$

for some $\alpha_{a,b}<1$, and this tends to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{\substack{a\lt b\\a,b\in\mathbb Q^+}}\bigcup_{n\geqslant 0}\left\{X_n\in (a,b)\right\}\right)=1$$
because for each $a,b\in\mathbb Q^+$ such that $a\lt b$, 
$$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n\geqslant 0}\left\{X_n\notin (a,b)\right\}\right)\leqslant \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n= 0}^N\left\{X_n\notin (a,b)\right\}\right)=\left(\mathbb P\left\{X_1\in \left(a,b\right)\right\}\right)^{N+1}$$
and for each $a,b\in\mathbb R^+$ such that $a\lt b$, $\mathbb P\left\{X_1\in (a,b)\right\}\lt 1$. Remark that this is the only property of the distribution of $X_1$ we have used. In particular, this is not specific to exponential distribution.